# XSL for-each loop with param returns no values

Tags: xml, xslt

So i've got the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<couriersystem title="Courier System"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="system.xsd">
    <branches>
        <branch bid="1">
            <name>Headquarters</name>
            <address>
                58, Main Street, Edinburgh, R79 2LR
            </address>
            <manager mid="1" />
            <headoffice hid="1" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="None" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="2">
            <name>Convenience Local Branch</name>
            <address>
                118, Renfrew Avenue, Dumfries, J6 8CZ
            </address>
            <manager mid="2" />
            <headoffice hid="1" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="Bicycle" />
                <method name="Car" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="3">
            <name>Westwood Shopping Centre</name>
            <address>
                119, London Street, Nidrie, F57 8NE
            </address>
            <manager mid="3" />
            <headoffice hid="1" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="Bicycle" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="4">
            <name>Logistics Warehouse</name>
            <address>
                160, Main Road, Dunfermline, A15 0PO
            </address>
            <manager mid="4" />
            <headoffice hid="1" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="Car" />
                <method name="Van" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="5">
            <name>Kingdom of Fife Shopping Centre</name>
            <address>
                92, Central Lane, Dunfermline, U38 2OD
            </address>
            <manager mid="5" />
            <headoffice hid="7" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="Bicycle" />
                <method name="Car" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="6">
            <name>Capital Branch</name>
            <address>
                95, High Street, Inverness, W91 8IW
            </address>
            <manager mid="6" />
            <headoffice hid="7" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="Car" />
                <method name="Van" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="7">
            <name>Glasgow City</name>
            <address>
                94, Harris Place, BathgateGlasgow, E74 2MR
            </address>
            <manager mid="7" />
            <headoffice hid="1" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="Car" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="8">
            <name>Edinburgh Omni Centre</name>
            <address>
                119, West Road, Edinburgh, A79 2EG
            </address>
            <manager mid="8" />
            <headoffice hid="1" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="None" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
        <branch bid="9">
            <name>Royal Plaza</name>
            <address>
                81, Royal Plaza, Bathgate, U52 7GV
            </address>
            <manager mid="9" />
            <headoffice hid="7" />
            <!-- delivery methods -->
            <deliverymethods>
                <method name="Bicycle" />
                <method name="Car" />
            </deliverymethods>
        </branch>
    </branches>
    <employees>
        <employee eid="1">
            <nin>AZ123518D</nin>
            <firstname>Peter</firstname>
            <lastname>Smith</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1994-02-11</dob>
            <email>ps11@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                119, London Street, Nidrie, F57 8NE
            </address>
            <tel>07005748900</tel>
            <salary>30526</salary>
            <empbranch bid="1" />
            <supervisor sid="1" />
        </employee>
        <employee eid="2">
            <nin>CN174869F</nin>
            <firstname>Jennifer</firstname>
            <lastname>Black</lastname>
            <gender>Female</gender>
            <dob>1984-12-24</dob>
            <email>jb21@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                161, South Road, Nidrie, W79 8WG
            </address>
            <tel>07555111222</tel>
            <salary>40576</salary>
            <empbranch bid="2" />
            <supervisor sid="1" />
        </employee>
        <employee eid="3">
            <nin>ET127654M</nin>
            <firstname>Aaron</firstname>
            <lastname>Jones</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1968-03-15</dob>
            <email>aj31@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                66, High Road, Yoker, Q47 4SR
            </address>
            <tel>07856471267</tel>
            <salary>30526</salary>
            <empbranch bid="3" />
            <supervisor sid="1" />
        </employee>
        <!-- snip -->
    </employees>
</couriersystem>
```

And I'm trying to use this xsl document below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- datetime2.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1 class="title">Courier System - Branches</h1><hr /><br />
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#all">Show All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#bymanager">By Manager</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <!-- show all -->
                <h2 id="all">All Branches</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Branch Name</th>
                        <th>Delivery Methods</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//branch">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@bid" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="address" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:for-each select="deliverymethods/method">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />,
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
                <a class="anchor-top" href="#">Back to top</a>

                <!-- by manager -->
                <h2 id="bymanager">Show Branches by Manager</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Branch Name</th>
                        <th>Delivery Methods</th>
                        <th>Manager</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//branch">
                        <xsl:sort select="manager/@mid" order="ascending" />
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@bid" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="address" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:for-each select="deliverymethods/method">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />,
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:call-template name="showManager">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="mid" select="manager/@mid" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
                <a class="anchor-top" href="#">Back to top</a>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="show_title" match="//employees">
        <xsl:param name="mid" />
        <xsl:for-each select="employee[@eid=$mid]">
            <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to show the firstname of each manager in the manager column on line: **171**. This is done using the template and parameter i send through.

However, my XML page when run just shows a blank screen so there is an error somewhere but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the XSLT is applied at all? Chrome for instance needs to be started with lowered security settings to apply an XSLT stylesheet to an XML document loaded from the local file system. As you get a blank page although you have static content you should see that static content at least.

Comment: Yeah it works without that expression @MartinHonnen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `xsl:call-template name="showManager"` but `xsl:template name="show_title"`. I don't see a need for `call-template`, define a key `<xsl:key name="mid" match="employee" use="@eid"/>`, then in place of the `call-template` use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('mid', manager/@mid)"/>
```

and have a template

```
<xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
</xsl:template>
```

If you know there can only be one manager reference then obviously you don't need the `<xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>` check.